# I cannot figure out how to use a csv file for a list comprehension in scrapinghub deployment

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I'm trying to deploy a spider to scrapinghub and cannot figure out how to tackle a data input problem. I need to read IDs from a csv and append them to my start urls as a list comprehension for the spider to crawl:

```
class exampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "exampleSpider"

    #local scrapy method to extract data
    #PID = pd.read_csv('resources/PID_list.csv')

    #scrapinghub method
    csvdata = pkgutil.get_data("exampleSpider", "resources/PID_list.csv")


    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/PID=' + str(x) for x in csvdata]
```

The requirements file and pkgutil.get_data parts works but I'm stuck on converting the data IO into the list. What's the process for converting the data call into the list comprehension?

EDIT:
Thanks! This got me 90% of the way there!

```
class exampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "exampleSpider"

    #local scrapy method to extract data
    #PID = pd.read_csv('resources/PID_list.csv')

    #scrapinghub method
    csvdata = pkgutil.get_data("exampleSpider", "resources/PID_list.csv")
    csvio = StringIO(csvdata)
    raw = csv.reader(csvio)

    # TODO : update code to get exact value from raw 
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/PID=' + str(x[0]) for x in raw]
```

The str(x) needed str(x[0]) as a quick fix since the loop was reading in the square brackets in url encoding which broke the links:
`str(x)` resulted in "http://www.example.com/PID=%5B'0001'%5D"
but `str(x[0])` gets it out of the list brackets: "http://www.example.com/PID='0001'"

Comment: How does PID_list.csv look like? Can you include a few lines?

Comment: The list is a csv that looks like: 0001,0002,0003

Comment: That looks like a comma-separated list (items are on the same line, separated by commas), not a CSV (rows are separated by new lines, columns are separated by a separating character like a comma). Can you confirm that the file is actually a command-separated list of IDs?

Answer (score 1):

```
class exampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "exampleSpider"

    #local scrapy method to extract data
    #PID = pd.read_csv('resources/PID_list.csv')

    #scrapinghub method
    csvdata = pkgutil.get_data("exampleSpider", "resources/PID_list.csv")
    csvio = StringIO(csvdata)
    raw = csv.reader(csvio)

    # TODO : update code to get exact value from raw 
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/PID=' + str(x) for x in raw]
```

You can use StringIO to turn a string into something with a read() method, which csv.reader should be able to handle. I hope this will help you :)